# What does "100% accept rate" means in my Questions?

Tags: support, accept-rate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accepting answers, what’s it all about?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/accepting-answers-whats-it-all-about)

Whenever I asked any question in SO I see following texts under my Name and reputation:

```
100% accept rate  or
90% accept rate  or
80% accept rate  or
50% accept rate
```

What does it means ??????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a percentage of how many questions that you've asked, and have selected an answer for.

Given a low percentage people are more reluctant to provide you with an answer, but this is only if your percentage is extremely low.